# Atlas - Export one image for each street of multiple areas

Tags: qgis, export, image, atlas

I have 2 layers:

- OSM roads polyline layer
- various area polygon layer

I need to export each area with every road highlighted.

Here are 2 exemples of export of the same area with 2 differents roads:

[image]

[image]

I selected the road manually and saved the image manually.

The problem is that there are about 10 areas with more than 100 roads.

Is it possible to automate the image export for each areas and roads ?

With the atlas tool I can export automatically each areas with this window:

[image]

Exemples of 2 areas:

[image]

[image]

How can I highlight every road one by one for each area and export it as image automatically ?

Comment: What failed exactly ? Describe what you did...

Comment: Thanks for your edits. Do i understand correctly if i say you need for example a 1000 pages atlas with 10 different bounds and for each bound times 100 roads number of pages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to basically export an atlas with the following settings, for each area.

Let's take an example (it's sunday, i was in a childish mood) :

- Your "coverage" layer would be the roads on a unique id field "id_field"
- Every road should know it's areas -> add a field "area_id" with the area it belongs too. If a road is over 2 areas, break it (to have only the area part) or make a duplicate with another area name (if you need to see all the road)

[image: roads and areas]

- Filter the roads and the areas for a specific area (area_id = 'NORTH')
- Style the roads with a special rule based symbol : `"id_field" = @atlaspagename`

[image: atlaspagename]

- Export all the roads of a single area. You can set the export name like the following :  `"area-id"  || '-' ||  "id_field"` for example.

[image: export north area]

- Change area and filters

You could also use a flat table with every possibility and x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max columns for extent + a visibility column but it would be much too long to explain here.